# How to validate with regex that a string is OK as long as it contains 10 digits?

Tags: regex

I'm processing input from a Web form. Basically, all I care about is that the value provided includes 10 digits, no more, no less.

These would be **valid** inputs:

```
1234567890
123 456 789 0 Hello!
My number is: 123456-7890 thanks
```

These would be **invalid** inputs:

```
123456789033 (too long)
123 Hello! (too short)
My number is one five zero nine thanks (no digits)
```

I've tried many different things with [Regextester](http://www.regextester.com/) but it never matches correctly. I'm using the 'preg' setting (which is what I figured my CMS Typo3 uses) and my closest attempt is:

```
([0-9][^0-9]*){10}
```

which is kinda lame but is the closest I got.

Cheers!

**EDIT: I cannot use any programming language to implement this. Imagine that I have a admin console field in front of me, in which I must enter a regular expression that will be used to validate the value. That's all the latitude I have.  Cheers.**

Comment: Must you use regular expressions for this? It would be easier and simpler to write a function to count the number of digits in a string, and then compare that to 10.

Comment: Greg: If you think it would be easier and simpler, by all means post the function as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

I think you've got the right idea. Maybe you can simplify it as `(\d\D*){10}`

If the regex has to match the complete string, you would want `\D*(\d\D*){10}`

UPDATE: It looks like you need `^\D*(\d\D*){10}$` to make sure you match the complete string.

Comment: I think you need `(\D*\d\D*)` to match strings that don't start with a number, as in the third example match.

Comment: Thanks guys. The closest seems to be:'(\D*\d\D*){10}' but it still matches too much. For example, if I have 12345678904444444444, this returns 4 matches: 1234567890,4444444444,0,4. (These last 2 matches are a complete mystery to me.) Cheers!

Comment: @Adam: I see, it looks like you might need my 3rd example.

Comment: @Gabe: Maybe I'm doing something wrong but the third example does not work for me. If I test `1234567890`, it matches `1234567890` and `0`. If I test `12345678909`, there are no matches. Thanks again!

Comment: @Adam: I thought you said you want to match exactly 10 digits. `12345678909` has 11 digits, so don't you expect it *not* to match?

Comment: @Gabe: DERP! I feel so stupid now! You're exactly right, I don't know what I was thinking! I'm going to use that one then. I still don't understand why it returns two matches `1234567890` and `0` but it hardly matters since they're always returned together when the string is correct. Thanks again for your precious help!

Comment: @Adam when you say "4 matches", it makes me think that maybe your testing function is returning the actual expression that was matched rather than a 1=true,0=false result. Maybe you want to use non-capturing groups in your regex: `^\D*(?:\d\D*){10}$`

Comment: @mob: Fantastic! It seems that was the missing piece of the puzzle. This now works flawlessly. Thank you very much!

Comment: Perfect way to validate 10-digit phone numbers!

Answer (score 1):

A regular expression is not always the best tool for this kind of job. In this case it's probably easier and simpler to write a function to count the number of digits in a string. (Since you didn't mention a programming language, I'll use Python in my example.)

```
def count_digits(s):
    return len([x for x in s if x.isdigit()])
```

Then, you can use it like this:

```
s = "My number is: 123456-7890 thanks"
if count_digits(s) == 10:
    print("looks okay")
else:
    print("doesn't contain 10 digits")
```

Comment: Thanks Greg. I clarified my initial post to say that I cannot use a programming language in that context. Sorry.

Comment: Okay. I hope this answer will be useful for somebody else who has a similar question.

Comment: It's not clear how procedural Python code will be useful to somebody looking for a regex.